# Enum is causing ExceptionInInitializerError in Groovy 2.x

Tags: exception, groovy, static, enums

My enum:

```
enum ServiceEnvironment implements ServiceEnvironmentStatics {
    Local(LOCAL_URI),
    Sandbox(SANDBOX_URI),
    Production(PRODUCTION_URI)

    private final String uri

    private ServiceEnvironment(String uri) {
        super()

        this.uri = uri
    }
}

interface ServiceEnvironmentStatics {
    static final String LOCAL_URI = "localhost:8080"
    static final String SANDBOX_URI = "sandbox.myapi.example.com"
    static final String PRODUCTION_URI = "myapi.example.com"
}
```

When I use this in code like so:

```
ServiceEnvironment env = ServiceEnvironment.Local
```

I get:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: com.me.myapp.ServiceEnvironment(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments1(MetaClassImpl.java:1490)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1409)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
    at com.me.myapp.ServiceEnvironment.$INIT(ServiceEnvironment.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:173)
    at com.me.myapp.ServiceEnvironment.<clinit>(ServiceEnvironment.groovy)
    ... 36 more
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Remove the `super()` invocation from your `enum` constructor.

**The Actual Answer:** The sole superclass of all `enum` classes is `java.lang.Enum`, which does not have a no-argument constructor. Therefore the line `super()` is in error. The runtime error here is rather misleading, due to the nature of dynamic method/constructor dispatch in Groovy. If we were instead to try to compile a roughly equivalent `enum` class in Java:

```
public enum ServiceEnvironment {
    Local("localhost:8080"),
    Sandbox("sandbox.myapi.example.com"),
    Production("myapi.example.com");

    private final String uri;

    private ServiceEnvironment(String uri) {
        super();
        this.uri = uri;
    }
}
```

The compiler would directly tell us that the `super()` statement is the problem. My Java compiler says:

```
Cannot invoke super constructor from enum constructor ServiceEnvironment(String)
```

...which makes much more sense at compile-time than the message that Groovy is giving at runtime.

Comment: If the individual who voted this answer down would be so kind as to explain the problem with it I would greatly appreciate it.